# Is there any way to manually add footer(some text) on the splash screen in IONIC 4?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I want a splash screen which has a logo(image) in the center and has footer(some text like,version number,company name). Can anyone please help out?

Comment: Add some more information and also the what you have tried and where you stuck.

Comment: I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dPUmskG_-y0&t=85s
Watch the first 1:44 mins

I have added the company logo but I am not able to add a footer to it

Comment: There is no canonical way to alter splash (unless you modify your image). But you can do something like what Josh did:https://www.joshmorony.com/creating-an-animated-splash-screen-in-ionic/ - basically use modal or something to fake transition to splash screen that you control

Answer (score 0):

you can create an image to use as a splash screen and add what you want

Comment: Yes, that is one solution But can we add text in the splash screen by code?
Does this mean splash screen should always be image ?

Comment: You can make it by making a custom page as a splach screen